# Trig, placing items and updating their position

Tags: lua, cairo

I have a problem I just cannot solve, and after a week it's really winding me up.

Background.

I'm placing items onto a circle using basic trig. The number of items can change dynamically, and they are spaced around the circle equally.

The items rotate around the circle, and the speed of rotation changes to be in sync with a BPM (Beats Per Minute) clock. This clock can change at any time.

The problem I'm having is that the items seem to be placed randomly on the circle, not equally spaced in order (see image 1). They'll appear out of order even though it's a basic for loop that places them. I think they may in face be in order, but the rotation values may be off making them look like they are in an odd order.

[image: image 1]

The second issue is that when the number of items reduces, the speed of rotation increases (it shouldn't) and if the number increases, the speed slows.

So I expect an issue with my trig function. I'm showing the complete code here but can simplify if it'll help.

What have I tried?

I've tried simplified versions without the graphical output, and the numbers all seem to make perfect sense. The radians between items is correct, the placement looks correct. It all looks correct, but it isn't.

The code.

```
--the variables
orbitalCircle.xPos = x or 0
orbitalCircle.yPos = y or 0
orbitalCircle.circleDiameter = diameter or 10
orbitalCircle.numberOfNotes = number_of_notes
orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes = (360 / number_of_notes)
orbitalCircle.beatsPerSecond = (beats_per_minute / 60)
orbitalCircle.currentRotation = 0
orbitalCircle.framesPerSecond = frames_per_second or 15
orbitalCircle.framesPerFullRotation = (orbitalCircle.numberOfNotes/orbitalCircle.beatsPerSecond)+orbitalCircle.framesPerSecond
orbitalCircle.degreesPerFrame = 360 / orbitalCircle.framesPerFullRotation
orbitalCircle.newRotationValue = orbitalCircle.currentRotation + orbitalCircle.degreesPerFrame
orbitalCircle.sequenceData = sequence_data

--the function that updates the sequence data and therefore the number of items on the circle
function orbitalCircle.updateNotes(sq)
    orbitalCircle.sequenceData = sq
    orbitalCircle.numberOfNotes = (#sq)
    orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes = (360 / orbitalCircle.numberOfNotes)
end

--the function that calculates the new rotation value of the item to be placed on the circle
    function orbitalCircle.tick()
        orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes = (360 / number_of_notes)
        orbitalCircle.framesPerFullRotation = (orbitalCircle.numberOfNotes/orbitalCircle.beatsPerSecond)*orbitalCircle.framesPerSecond
        orbitalCircle.degreesPerFrame = (360 / orbitalCircle.framesPerFullRotation)
        orbitalCircle.newRotationValue = (orbitalCircle.currentRotation + orbitalCircle.degreesPerFrame)

        if orbitalCircle.newRotationValue > 360 then
            orbitalCircle.currentRotation = 0
        else
            orbitalCircle.currentRotation = orbitalCircle.newRotationValue
        end
    end

--finally the function that places the items onto the circle
    function orbitalCircle.redraw()
        screen.circle(orbitalCircle.xPos, orbitalCircle.yPos, orbitalCircle.circleDiameter)
        screen.stroke()
        for i=1, (#orbitalCircle.sequenceData) do
            if orbitalCircle.sequenceData[i] > 0 then
                    screen.circle(
                        math.cos(math.rad(orbitalCircle.newRotationValue)+(orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes*i))*orbitalCircle.circleDiameter + orbitalCircle.xPos,
                        math.sin(math.rad(orbitalCircle.newRotationValue)+(orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes*i))*orbitalCircle.circleDiameter + orbitalCircle.yPos,
                        map(orbitalCircle.sequenceData[i], 5, 128, 0.5, 4)
                    )
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

I'd expect that the items would be:

- equally spaced no matter the amount (that works)
- in order (they appear not to be)
- the speed of rotation should remain fixed unless the BPM changes (this doesn't happen)

I'm lost!

Comment: What are you doing this in? Conky? What's your cairo bindings? Conky's built-in bindings? Is the code that you showed the full code that can be run in conky?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a closer look at the drawing.

```
screen.circle(
    math.cos(math.rad(orbitalCircle.newRotationValue)+(orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes*i))*orbitalCircle.circleDiameter + orbitalCircle.xPos,
    math.sin(math.rad(orbitalCircle.newRotationValue)+(orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes*i))*orbitalCircle.circleDiameter + orbitalCircle.yPos,
    map(orbitalCircle.sequenceData[i], 5, 128, 0.5, 4)
)
```

What is the angle that is being drawn here? It is the argument to `math.cos` and `math.sin` (I will ignore the scaling and the translation that is applied afterwards):

```
math.rad(orbitalCircle.newRotationValue)+(orbitalCircle.spaceBetweenNotes*i)
```

So... it is the `neRotationValue` converted to radians and added to that the space between notes. This one is defined as `360 / number_of_notes`, so it is in degrees. Adding a radians and degrees most likely does not produce the expected result.

So, what exactly do you mean with the following?

> I've tried simplified versions without the graphical output, and the numbers all seem to make perfect sense.